# Mono TLS1.2 issues - btls-cert-sync "command not found"

Tags: c#, .net, docker, mono

### Summary:

My company uses TargetProcess (TP) to track progress on open projects and we've created a relatively small bit of code that imports updates to TargetProcess.
Currently upon build submission, we spin up a debian docker image, with Mono pre-installed, and it runs our small .NET(C#) program to connect our updates to TP.

### Repro:

It appears TP recently updated their API to only accept TLS1.2 connections, so we had to create a new docker image with Mono 4.8, the Alpha channel, on it (per this [article](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2016/Sep-30.html)). 
The program still doesn't work out of the box with this new Mono installation on a docker image so we took a few steps: (following the prompting from Mono's Security FAQ)

```
// Made sure that the most current version ca-certificates-mono is installed
// and it seems to have been installed upon installation of mono 4.8
apt-get install ca-certificates-mono

// This should be an unnecessary step from what I read, but ran anyway 
cert-sync /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

// lastly btls-cert-sync command, but can't seem to get it to not return
// "command not found" no matter wher I try running it
btls-cert-sync
```

### Testing:

There seems to be a really helpful [thread](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/TLS-1-2-to-ship-in-Mono-4-8-Discussion-Topic-td4669273.html) on how to test if your certs are formatted correctly. After running this test command in my docker image, I'm still seeing the failure message below.

```
MONO_TLS_PROVIDER=btls csharp -e 'Console.WriteLine (new System.Net.WebClient ().DownloadString ("https://www.howsmyssl.com/").IndexOf ("1.2"))'

// error message
System.Net.WebException: Error: TrustFailure (Ssl error:1000007d:SSL routines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED) ---> Mono.Btls.MonoBtlsException: Ssl error:1000007d:SSLroutines:OPENSSL_internal:CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED
```

Any help or advice to get our instance of mono to accept TLS1.2 connections would be awesome.

Comment: did you find an answer to your question?

Comment: We ended up creating a route around the TLS issue by creating a standing server to route our calls coming off of mono from!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`btls-cert-sync` is a shell script for `btls-cert-sync.exe`

Find `btls-cert-sync.exe`, normally installed in `4.8.0/lib/mono/4.8` and run it with `mono`:

```
mono btls-cert-sync.exe
```

Comment: Doing a find on our docker image, we can't find any files containing "btls" in them to be run - which leads me to believe it may not have been installed and/or carried over to the docker image.

Comment: did an apt-cache trying to find if maybe we didn't install the btls package needed - only could find the package "libmono-btls-interface4.0-cil" which doesn't seem to give access to the "btls-cert-sync" exe.

Answer (score 1):

As of mono 4.8 beta 3, btls-cert-sync seems to have been merged into cert-sync.

Do make sure that you have an up-to-date version of cert-sync as it is possible to get old versions of cert-sync still installed even if you have updated mono because the ca-certificates-mono package has not been updated (Linux).

If you look at the cert-sync output you will see

```
Mono Certificate Store Sync - version 4.8.0.0
...
Importing into legacy system store:
...
Importing into BTLS system store:
...
```