# Mono says certificate is invalid OpenSSL says certificate is valid

Tags: c#, ssl, mono, lets-encrypt

I have a mono software that connects to a website. In my case an Let's Encrypt secured website. After the certificate was updated Mono tells me that the certificate is invalid. If i check the URL with OpenSSL it tells me that the certificate is valid.

I tried to update the certificate store i tried to update the mono certificate store. Nothing helps.

Anyone any suggestions what i should do?

```
Mono.Security.Protocol.Tls.TlsException: Invalid certificate received from server. Error code: 0x0
```

Comment: Which version of Mono? Are you using Mono's BoringSLL? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41354313/4984832 https://stackoverflow.com/a/42011402/4984832

Comment: Mono JIT compiler version 4.2.3 (Stable 4.2.3.4/832de4b So 30. Dez 12:10:55 CET 2018)

Comment: I try now a newer Mono Version (4.8.1). Maybe this solves the problem

Comment: No success after updating to 4.8.1. It worked until i updated the certificate. Now it does not work anymore... Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it solved. After removing the OLD Mono V4.8.1 and replacing it with Mono V 5.10 all is good. Certificate is valid now.

Greetings

Christian Nill